# How to map application property onto a map in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, yaml

I have this application.yaml file that has the following tag which is of interest:

```
   hardware:
      sensor:
        enable: false
        type: 'sensor'
      interface:
        enable: false
        type: 'interface-pcb'
      printer:
        enable: false
        type: mock #or bixolon or epson
      camera:
        enable: true
        type: mock #or joyusing
      fingerprint:
        enable: true
        type: mock #or secugen
      document:
        enable: true
        type: mock #or wentone
      barcode-scanner:
        enable: true
        type: mock #or honeywell
        timeout: 25 #must not be greater than 30
```

I want to be able to get the type of each hardware dynamically. I want to use a Map for this case that I could use.

A sample of the map I want:

```
"sensor": enable: true
        : type: mock
```

How can I achieve this using Spring Boot and Java 8?

Comment: PLEAS NOTE I CANNOT CHANGE THE YAML

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that holds the properties and use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to map the properties in `application.yml`:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfProperties {
    private Map<String, Hardware> hardware;

    public Map<String, Hardware> getHardware() {
        return hardware;
    }

    public void setHardware(Map<String, Hardware> hardware) {
        this.hardware = hardware;
    }

    public static class Hardware{
        private boolean enable;
        private String type;
        private int timeout;

        public boolean isEnable() {
            return enable;
        }

        public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
            this.enable = enable;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public int getTimeout() {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the configuration:

```
@Autowired
ConfProperties confProperties;
```